# Finding the cumulative distribution function of variable R2 -> R1

Tags: statistics

Let there be a random variable $Z$ defined as $Z = g(X, Y)$ where $g$ is some function perhaps of the form $g(X, Y) = X + Y$ and where $X$ and $Y$ are known random variables.

Our function $g: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^1}$, thus no inverse exists.

$F_Z$ is the CDF of $Z$.

Now, we can say that...
$$F_Z(z) = \mathbb P(Z \le z)$$

$$= \mathbb P(g(X, Y) \le z)$$

Is there anything we can do from here to write $F_Z$ in terms of $F_{X,Y}$ the joint CDF of $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F_Z(z)$ can be calculated directly in some cases using specific knowledge about $g.$ For example, if $g(x,y)=x+y,$ $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y\le z)=\int \mathbb{P}(X\le z-y)f_Y(y)dy,$$

essentially breaking up the event $(X+Y\le z)$ into disjoint events $X\le z-y, Y\in(y-\partial y,y+\partial y).$

An indirect method will be to find the distribution of $t(X,Y)=(g(X,Y),h(X,Y)).$ This is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and there is a possibility that $t$ is invertible. If that is the case, its distribution can be found using transformation of random variables. See page 4 of [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf) lecture note.

Thus we have the joint distribution of $(A,B)$ where $A=g(X,Y)$ and $B=h(X,Y).$ Now integrate out $B$ to find the marginal distribution of $A.$